# which database should I use for simple log in register form in android

Tags: android, database, authentication

I am a beginner and I want to develop a chat application. The first page have log in and sign up options. Every user have username(using in chat). So which database should I use? I want to hold e-mails, usernames and passwords. I really confused with databases. Appreciate all helps.

Comment: are you creating one chat app ?

Comment: have you tried googling?

Comment: you can use sqlite database for that ...

Comment: yes only one chat app every user in same area(not in a different room), also there is broadcast video but thats not relative my problems. I only want to learn which database should I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a little information to save like UserName and Password  then [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is good for you.

If you want to store a little huge amount of data for only your app then `SQLite database` and data you want to share in other applications  also then `ContentProvider`. Both are [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

If you want to maintain your data both in server side and client side then you can use some Global Databases like `Oracle`, `SQL Server` etc which are maintained by your server site with some `Web Services` or `Web Apis`.

NOTE: You can use `SharedPreferences` and `SQLite` when you don't want to share data out of your application.

As for the Chat App I think you should use a Database which can be maintained by your Server Site through a Web Service/Api.